# Get email address in buildfire app social login plugin

Tags: facebook-login, buildfire, twitter-login

I am using buildfire social login plugin, it is creating user account via social login option but it is not giving the user email address. How can I grab the user email address on regitration.

Answer (score 1):

Using the BuildFire API, you can make can call **buildfire.auth.getCurrentUser(callback)**.

For example:

```
buildfire.auth.getCurrentUser(function(err, user){
    console.log('user', user);
}
```

[SDK](https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/How-to-use-Auth#buildfireauthgetcurrentusercallback)